# jQuery Focus() not responding?

Tags: jquery, focus

I have a mega menu for which I'm trying to add in keyboard accessibility. From my (limited) understanding, this should work:

```
$('nav li').focus(function() { $(this).hover() });
$('nav li').hover(
    function() { $(this).addClass('active'); },
    function() { $(this).removeClass('active'); }
);
```

Yet, it doesn't. The `hover()` works fine, but I figured just calling `focus()` as another trigger, it'd work but it doesn't. Even if I write it out:

```
$('nav li').hover(
    function() { $(this).addClass('active'); },
    function() { $(this).removeClass('active'); }
);

$('nav li').focus(
    function() { $(this).addClass('active'); },
    function() { $(this).removeClass('active'); }
);
```

It still will not. I'm still learning so any help is appreciated. Also, is there's a way to consolidate the `hover` & `focus` into one statement instead of two?

Thanks!

### *//Update*

Here's a link to the [site-in-progress](http://www.tahlequah.k12.ok.us/test/newSite) for better understanding.

Comment: I'm still open to suggestions on this; I want to accept an answer but I still would like to have keyboard access to the links in the submenu.

Answer (score 2):

`li` elements do not have a `focus` event by default. You can make them accept focus by adding a `tabindex` attribute to the `li` elements in question. That should solve your problem, as your code looks fine to me otherwise.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqrNZ/) for a working example.

Another option would be to use a `click` event instead of `focus`, which won't require any modification to the `li` elements, although whether this suits your needs would depend on what you're actually trying to do.

However, as you're running the same code in your `hover` and `focus` events, why do you need a `focus` event at all?

Comment: Thanks for the info, didn't think about `li`'s not having focus events. However, adding `tabindex` doesn't help me. I've updated my question with a link to the site-in-progress.

Comment: I'm still not clear on why you need to apply a `focus` event to the `li` elements... can you shed any light on that?

Comment: It's not a necessity, mostly a curiosity. I'm just trying to figure out a way for users to display & have access to the submenu via their keyboard. The `a` link inside of the top-level `li` doesn't wrap around the entire submenu (as I've seen done), so I have to have a `hover` & `focus` placed on the top-level `li` & not the top-level `a`. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('nav li').focus(function() { $(this).trigger('hover') });
```

instead of

```
$('nav li').focus(function() { $(this).hover() });
```

Comment: Under the hood, `.hover` results in `.trigger('hover')`.

Answer (score 0):

What is "nav" on your page?  If it's a class, you'll likely need to change your jquery selector to something like this:

```
$('.nav li')
```

or maybe...

```
$('li.nav')
```

...if the CSS class is applied to the LI element itself.

Comment: `nav` is probably an HTML5 `nav` element: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-nav-element

Comment: I've updated my question with a link to the site-in-progress.

Comment: Ah, understood.  None of my current clients are looking at HTML5 yet, so it's been off my radar.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate for better performance. You can try the below code hope it helps you.

```
$('nav').delegate('li', 'focus mouseover', function() { 
  $(this).addClass('active'); 
}).delegate('li', 'blur mouseout', function() { 
  $(this).removeClass('active'); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this code worked. I will consider it as an option.

Comment: @Max - I am glad it helped you please vote and accept if you are finally going with this.

Comment: Your answer was partly what I'm looking for. While it did work for the tabbing & showing the submenus, it did not allow keyboard access to the submenus. I'll have to keep researching a bit more. I am not ready to accept an answer just yet.